# Throwing nullpointerexception for nested bean that autowired in Junit mockito test case

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, code-coverage

I have Junit test case for service layer, from service method logic calling some other beans with autowired and in the unit test case I used that bean as Autowired beacuse that also should cover as part of code coverage.

```
class CustomerServiceTest{

   @Autowired(or InjectMocks)
   private EmployeeService employeeService;

   @Autowired
   private CustomerService customerService;

   @Test
   public void testcustomerIdNotNull() {
       //mocking some repository call
       Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerDetails();
       //all other test case code
   }
}

 //Customer Service code
 @Service
 public class CustomerService{

 @Autowired
 EmployeeService employeeService;

 public Customer getCustomerDetails() {
       //some code
      employeeService.getEmployee();   /// **Here it was throwing nullpointerexception** 
    //some logic and complete code
 }
}
```

I tried Autowired with Spy but didn't work.

Comment: what about annotate the class with ‘@SpringBootTest’, because I don’t see it in your code.

Comment: and also what version of `jUnit` are you using ? 4 or 5 ?

Comment: `@InjectMocks` will create a new instance, not use the one from the application context. Are all beans available in your context? Do you run the test as Spring Boot test (`@SpringBootTest`)? Do you use the correct context configuration?

Comment: Using Junit 5 version, with ExtendWith MockitoExtension.class

Comment: using `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is weird. And your comment suggests that you think that `@Autowired` and `@InjectMocks` are interchangable. They are absolutely not.

The first question you have to ask yourself is if you want to run a Spring Boot test (loading the application context) or if you want to execute a test that uses regular Java without Spring.

If you need a Spring Boot test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CustomerServiceTest{

  @MockBean // register a mock version of your repository bean
  private YourRepository yourRepository;

  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;

  @Test
  public void testcustomerIdNotNull() {
    // mocking some repository call ...
    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerDetails();
    // all other test case code
  }
}
```

If you don't need Spring's application context and want to mock your dependencies:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomerServiceTest{

  @Mock // creates a mock instance
  private YourRepository yourRepository;

  @InjectMocks // creates a real instance and injects mocks
  private CustomerService customerService;

  @Test
  public void testcustomerIdNotNull() {
    // mocking some repository call ...
    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerDetails();
    // all other test case code
  }
}
```

`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` of Mockito go together as do `@MockBean` and `@Autowired` of Spring Boot. You must not mix them.

IIRC, `@InjectMocks` should be able to inject fields, but if it doesn't move away from the discouraged method of field injection and migrate your class to constructor injection:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

  private final EmployeeService employeeService;

  @Autowired
  public CustomerService(final EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
  }

  public Customer getCustomerDetails() {
    //some code
    employeeService.getEmployee();
    //some logic and complete code
  }
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing to mark your fields as final.

Comment: I used the Mock and InjectMocks annotation and at class level used @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class). I posted the code so in Customer Service method employee service is coming as null and throwing null pointer exception , this is the code has an issue -----------                                                              
     public Customer getCustomerDetails() {
            employeeService.getEmployee();   /// **Here it was throwing 
                   nullpointerexception** 
       }
     }

Comment: @AnilNivargi perhaps field injection is a problem. I thought `@InjectMocks` can do it on a field level, but maybe it can not. Find my updated answer for how to use constructor-based injection.

Answer (score 0):

If the test class is annotated with the below annotations, it would work (JUnit 4)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

In case of JUnit 5, just annotating with `@SpringBootTest` should be sufficient. Refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications)

> If you are using JUnit 5, there is no need to add the equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and the other @…​Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Note that this loads the entire Spring Application context which is more suitable for integration testing.

From **unit testing** standpoint, it is recommended to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` with `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` combination (JUnit 4)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CustomerServiceTest{
   @Mock
   private EmployeeService employeeService;

   @InjectMocks
   private CustomerService customerService;

   @Test
   public void testcustomerIdNotNull() {
       //mocking some repository call
       Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerDetails();
       //all other test case code
   }
}
```

For Junit 5, replace `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

Comment: Using Junit 5 version

Comment: Added for junit5 as well

Answer (score 0):

Changed field level injection to constructer based injection and null pointer exception issue got resolved. I am using Junit 5.
Not shared the complete code here, just shared the issue code and flow. Below is the final working code,

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomerServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    private CustomerService customerService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        customerService = new CustomerService(employeeService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testcustomerIdNotNull() {
        //mocking some repository call, not shared all other repo code here
        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerDetails();
        //all other test case code
    }
}

 //Customer Service code
 @Service
 public class CustomerService{


 private final EmployeeService employeeService;

 @Autowired
 public CustomerService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
     this.employeeService = employeeService;
 }

 public Customer getCustomerDetails() {
       //some code
       employeeService.getEmployee();   /// fixed NPE issue
      //some logic and complete code
 }
}
```